# How to encrypt MongoDB database using Node js

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, encryption, mongoose

I have mongoDb database, I want all data to be encrypted, how we can do this by using nodejs. All the key values should be encrypted.

Comment: You can use bcrypt-nodejs package (or bcrypt)

Comment: This is not a concern with MongoDB. You can encrypt the data before storing it regardless of DB and maintain a master key.

Comment: @Lex can you please explain how we can do this, I am new to mongoDb, any help will be appreciated

Comment: @VishalRana take a look at this article https://lollyrock.com/posts/nodejs-encryption/ , set up a dummy node project to test it out. Encryption is a two way process that uses a hidden secret key to encode/decode. As long as you know the key you can decrypt. So prior to storing in Mongo `encrypt` plain text or objects. And when you want to read `decrypt`

Comment: Please verify wether you want the data on rest to be encrypted or the actual values. For the former, there is a plethora of options.

Answer (score 2):

This is not a concern with MongoDB. You can encrypt the data before storing it regardless of DB and maintain a master key.

Encryption is a two way process that uses a hidden secret key to encrypt/decrypt. As long as you know the master key you can decrypt. So prior to storing in Mongo `encrypt` plain text or objects. And when you want to read `decrypt`.

You'll add a performance overhead to encrypt/decrypt all your data. And you'll loose the ability to query data freely. But if it's sensitive user data you're taking the right path. As long as your master KEY is kept secret even if your database is stolen the data is still safe.

Take a look at this article https://lollyrock.com/posts/nodejs-encryption/ , and set up a dummy node project to test it out. Try encrypting and decrypting and print out the output.

Answer (score 1):

[MongoDB Enterprise](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/security-encryption-at-rest/) provides you option to encrypt the database.

You can use [Mongoose-encryption](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose-encryption) package for simple encryption and authentication of mongoose documents.

Comment: I am using Mongoose-encryption, but some of the methods are not working. Like find() is working but findOne() not.

Comment: `findOne()` is expected to work. But,if you had encrypted multiple documents at once,as per documentation,  you cannot select individual encrypted fields in a query nor unset or rename encrypted fields via an update operation.